# Expander button is not working properly in my wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, expander

Expander button is not working properly in my wpf datagrid. I am using the following template for expander button.

```
            <!-- MouseOver, Pressed behaviours-->
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                Value="#FF3C7FB1"
                                TargetName="Circle"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                Value="#222"
                                TargetName="Sign"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                Value="#FF526C7B"
                                TargetName="Circle"/>
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness"
                                Value="1.5"
                                TargetName="Circle"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                Value="#FF003366"
                                TargetName="Sign"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!-- Simple Expander Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleExpanderTemp" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <DockPanel>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" 
                          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                          Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderButtonTemp}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                          OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                          Padding="1.5,0">
            </ToggleButton>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent"
                              Grid.Row="1" 
                              Visibility="Collapsed"
                              DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ExpanderContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Also i am adding the following code for datagridtemplatecolumn.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="27">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Expander Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderTemp}" Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But if i am trying to expand one expander button in my wpf datagrid, some of the other expander buttons are also expanding(not every time) and some of the expander buttons are collapsing.

What is the error in this xaml code?

The expander events are,

```
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentControl cc = sender as ContentControl;
    Expander exp = cc as Expander;

    var itemsSource = objDatagrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (itemsSource != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = objDatagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null)
            {
                row.IsSelected = false;
            }

        }
    }
    for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
        if (vis is DataGridRow)
        {

            var row = (DataGridRow)vis;
            row.IsSelected = true;
            if (exp.IsExpanded)
            {
                row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                exp.ExpandDirection = ExpandDirection.Down;
            }
            break;
        }
}

private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemsSource = objDatagrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (itemsSource != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = objDatagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null)
            {
                row.IsSelected = false;
            }

        }
    }
    for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)

        if (vis is DataGridRow)
        {
            var row = (DataGridRow)vis;
            row.IsSelected = true;
            row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            break;
        }

}
```

Comment: What's in Expanded event handler?

Comment: @icebat : Expander events are included in my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You could try RowDetailsTemplate for the dataGrid. Also set the RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"

```
        <DataGrid  SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                        <!-- Content -->
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- Columns -->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```